# Getting object promise instead real data

Tags: javascript, datatable

i want to display test name in datatables but it shows [object promise] instead of actual data. I've tried various information on other people's questions but still can't. the problem is, when in console.log() the data appears in the console, but when it returns the value. view in datatables becomes [object promise]

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    table = $('#TblTestCategory').DataTable({
        "order": [],
        "drawCallback": function (settings) {
            var api = this.api();
            var startIndex = api.context[0]._iDisplayStart;
            var counter = startIndex + 1;
            api.column(0, { page: 'current' }).nodes().each(function (cell, i) {
                cell.innerHTML = counter;
                counter++;
            });
        },
        responsive: true,
        "ajax": {
            url: "https://localhost:7136/api/TestCategory",
            type: "GET",
            "datatype": "json",
            "dataSrc": "data",
        },
        "columns": [
{
                "data": "testKit",
                "orderable": false,
                "orderData": [1],
                "render": async function (data, type, row, meta) {
                    console.log(data);
                    const testName =  await generateString(data);
                    console.log(testName); // output: Test1, Test2, Test3
                    return testName;
                }  
            }
 ]
    });

const generateString = async (input) => {
        const arr = input.split(',');
        const testName = [];

            for (const number of arr) {
                const result = await $.ajax({
                    url: 'https://localhost:7136/api/Test/' + number,
                    type: 'GET',
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    dataType: "json"
                });
                testName.push(result.data.testName);
            }
            return testName.join(',');
    };
});
```

Comment: The problem is that you cannot set the `columns.render` property of a **DataTable** to an `async` function.

Comment: @Titus is there another way that people usually use?

Comment: Yes, instead of using **DataTable**'s `ajax` property, download the data yourself and go through it to download the columns data as well.